# How to know if I have trial version of visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My university has several programs available for download. About 6 months ago I downloaded visual studio 2010 ultimate edition. I am not sure if it is the trial version. I don't think so because I've been using it for about 6 months and I have not had to extend any trial. Moreover, I don't get the splash screen that says for evaluation purposes only. I used to have that screen on a trial of visual studio profesional edition that I had in my previos computer. If I dont have a trial version that means I can distribute my applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio you can see licensing information. Mine says that it is licensed to me (yay!) and yours should say something similar.

I am not sure about volume licensing, because ours has been bought through an Open Value contract and we have MSDN accounts for every developer, so you have to download your own product key from the MSDN site. Perhaps there are versions of 2010 which do not require you to enter a product key in a different volume licensing contract, but I am not aware of those.

Really though, if you are on a student edition you are not supposed to use it for commercial applications. Just be safe and buy a copy if you are going to distribute your applications (especially commercially).

Answer (score 3):

For those students out there, as a point of interest, Microsoft offers a lot of free software on [dreamspark.com](http://dreamspark.com) (Visual studio 2010 Professional included) in which you should have no problems distributing your own applications - You just need a .edu email.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether Visual Studio is prompting you to purchase a full version, you've obtained your copy via your university. Your best bet is to ask someone in your university's IT department.

You also probably signed an agreement as part of your enrolment which would clarify this.

Comment: I did that long time ago so I don't remember. I downloaded several things but I just kept the iso file. I guess I'll try to contact the IT department of my school. I was hoping I could do this by going to an about button in visual studio.